# Word for challenging a general idea or belief

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I need a word or phrase which can be used to describe someone or something challenging a general idea of belief. Here are some examples:

> They **challenge** the ethos of their particular eras and in turn, inflict personal and political change.
>
> In these sources, they investigate the intricacies of human interaction, and how the distribution of power can be altered through **challenging** the zeitgeists of the same country at two distinct points, one filled with racism and the latter with chaos.

I need terms to replace the word "challenge" in these examples. Any help will be strongly appreciated.

Comment: It might help to know why "challenge" isn't acceptable for your purposes.

Comment: Have you yet gone through the research processes that might get you to an answer?  You start by looking up in a thesaurus words close to what you seek but not quite right.  So try 'sceptic', or 'critical'; or 'disruptive' or 'disruptor' or 'reformer'; or 'rebel'.  You then look up the word and take each word listed and look it up in a good dictionary, studying carefully the examples of the word or phrase in use.  If you still cannot find what you are looking for, maybe you have to invent one - perhaps a hyphenated compound of two words.

Comment: Not so sure about "inflict...change." Maybe *introduce*, but inflict sounds painful.

Answer (score 1):

"To contend *against*" is a close synonym.

> (SOED)**4**  *v.i.* Argue (*with, against, etc.*)

They contend against the ethos of their particular eras and in turn, inflict personal and political change.

[Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22contend%20against%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1909,cd_max:2008&lr=lang_en) can be perused plenty of examples; by doing so a truer feel of the term can be gained.

[A telling sample](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Passages_for_Translation_Into_French_and/UgFKAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22contend+against%22&dq=%22contend+against%22&printsec=frontcover) The classical student has only to contend against other students who are and have been situated very much as he is situated himself.

This can be worded as follows.

- The classical student has only to challenge other students who are and have been situated very much as he is situated himself.

Answer (score 0):

I looked through the thesaurus, and two words you may find useful are ‘contest’ and ‘denounce’.

Contest carries the meaning of arguing and questioning, similar to challenge:

> to struggle or fight for, as in battle.

> to argue against; dispute:
> to contest a controversial question; to contest a will.

> to call in question:
> They contested his right to speak.

While Denounce has the feeling of ‘attacking’: *to condemn or censure openly or publicly*

Using these in your sample:

> They **contest** the ethos of their particular eras and in turn, inflict personal and political change.

> In these sources, they investigate the intricacies of human interaction, and how the distribution of power can be altered through **denouncing** the zeitgeists of the same country at two distinct points, one filled with racism and the latter with chaos.